# inserting element at the end of linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am trying to insert element at the end of linked list but the while loop doesn't terminate. I am not able to understand why is this happening. Here is my code.

I am calling this function inside my main() function.

```
struct node{
    int data;
    struct node* link;
};
struct node * head;


void insert_last(int element){ 

    struct node * temp  = (node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    temp->data = element;
    temp->link = NULL;

    if(head==NULL){
        head = temp;
    }

    struct node * temp1 = head;

    while(temp1->link!=NULL){
        temp1 = temp1->link;

    }

    temp1->link = temp;

}
```

Here is the main method:

```
int main()
{
    head = NULL;
    printf("Enter the no. of nodes or elements you want to make linked list of. ");
    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int element = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<n; i++){
        printf("Enter the element\n");
        scanf("%d",&element);
        insert_last(element);
        std::cout<<"Element inserted\n\n";
    }
    //print_recursive(head);
    print();
}
```

Comment: Please format your code properly, as a courtesy to your readers.

Comment: What is the reason to write a own linked list implementation?

Comment: To find out how lists work.

Comment: to improve my coding skills, get a better understanding :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's easy.

```
if(head==NULL){
    head = temp;
}
```

In that case, you are already done with what are you doing. If you continue, `temp1` becomes the `temp`. Then `temp1->link = temp;` makes this node point to itself. Second insertion will never find end because your list is circular now and `while(temp1->link!=NULL)` will never end.

What you should do is simply put `return;`.

```
if(head==NULL){
    head = temp;
    return;
}
```